# filtering documents containing three level nested arrays depending on the values in the most nested and least nested array mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would be very grateful for any help in such situation.
Collection in MongoDB (now only 3 objects for demonstration purpose):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "agentName" : "Digital Queen", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-16T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d86"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(2), 
    "agentName" : "Iron Lady", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-03T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d87"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(3), 
    "agentName" : "Proxy Agent", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-04-09T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to return only those documents that are only in a certain period of time. There must be a match in at least one of the fields: 1) "receivedDate" (which is located in the array at the first level of nesting - policyList) or 2) "policyStatusDate" (which is in the array at the third level of nesting - policiesArray). One match is enough, for example if I want to see documents from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022 I expect to see the first and second document (first document matches by policyStatusDate - 20/02/2022 and second document matches by receivedDate - 23/02/2022) and third document I don't expect to see because both dates in this document from April.

My aggregation request:

```
db.getCollection("offers").aggregate([
{
  $project: {
  "agentId": "$agentId",
  "agentName": "$agentName",
  "policyList": {
        $map: {
                input: "$policyList",
                as: "policies",
                in:  {
                  receivedDate: "$$policies.receivedDate",
                  policyStatusDetail: {
                    $map: {
                     input: "$$policies.policyStatusDetail",
                     as: "items",
                     in: {
                         policyStsCode: "$$items.policyStsCode",
                         policiesArray: {
                           $filter: {
                             input: "$$items.policiesArray",
                             as: "item",
                             cond: {
                               $or: [
                                {$and: [{$gte: ["$$policies.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-02-01")]},
                                    {$lte: ["$$policies.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-03-31")]}
                                    ]
                                    },
                                
                                {$and: [
                                    {$gte: ["$$item.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01")]},
                                    {$lte: ["$$item.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-31")]}
                                    ]}
                                ]
                             }
                           }
                         }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
        } 
    }
  }

}
])
```

I received all 3 documents instead of only first and second document. I received third document with all fields and field policiesArray (type of array) is empty (as a result of my query). If this array is empty it means that document is not in requested period of time because it didn't pass a check. But I don't need to see this document.
Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "agentName" : "Digital Queen", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-16T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d86"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(2), 
    "agentName" : "Iron Lady", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-03T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d87"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(3), 
    "agentName" : "Proxy Agent", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "policiesArray" : [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So my question is what I need to add to my query to avoid returning a documents with empty policiesArray (third nesting level array)? Maybe also there are better options how to make this query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Complete redo to fix logic** (hopefully)

The match stage needs just a single `true`/`false`, so nested `"$reduce"` can dive into each array element and evaluate/aggregate the condition.

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$policyList",
        "initialValue": false,
        "in": {
          "$or": [
            "$$value",
            {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$this.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$this.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$$this.policyStatusDetail",
                "initialValue": false,
                "in": {
                  "$or": [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      "$reduce": {
                        "input": "$$this.policiesArray",
                        "initialValue": false,
                        "in": {
                          "$or": [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                              "$and": [
                                { "$gte": [ "$$this.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                                { "$lte": [ "$$this.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SdJIeg1awh1).

Comment: Thank you, it really works. Tell me please, how it possible to convert this find query to aggregation query? Because my example consists only a part of the whole logic and I really need to use aggregation in real example.

Comment: @yakob I updated my answer to include an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is only one problem. It looks like implicit "and" operator (",") in our case works not correct. Try for example to change the date in both "and" constructions in such way that "$lte" date earlier than "$gte date (for example:
          "$gte": ISODate("2022-03-01"),
          "$lte": ISODate("2022-02-01")
 )" and mongo will still return a first document, but we expect 0 documents to return in such case.
  
I would be very grateful if someone could help me to solve this problem

Comment: @yakob OFC you are correct.  Sorry for the initial distraction and thanks for your detailed testing.  I completely rewrote the `"$match"`.  Please see if this works for you.  I'm kinda wondering if a javascript `"$function"` with recursive descent and early dismissal might be more efficient.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I hope it's the best desicion on this time

Comment: @yakob  If it works for you, please upvote and accept the answer so others will know that it works.

Comment: Sure, I did it. I also have another important question about aggregation in mongo. But I think better to create new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72050771/how-to-filter-data-in-collection-containing-documents-with-3-level-nested-arrays

Comment: could we talk about this query in private conversation, what do you think about it?

Comment: @yakob Chat room at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244364/mongodb-matching-deeply-nested-array-elements