# How to filter data in collection containing documents with 3 level nested arrays depending on the values in the first and last nested array mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I appreciate any help in such case. Collection in MongoDB (now only 4 documents for demonstration purpose):

```
   { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "agentName" : "Yardi Gaondi", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-16T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d86"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(2), 
    "agentName" : "Michelle Hazandi", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-04-09T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-09T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("626da96932cb6043086eae42"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(3), 
    "agentName" : "Barbie", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-05-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-05-16T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("626da96932cb6043086eae43"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(4), 
    "agentName" : "Mzandi", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-05-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-09T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-10T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-09T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So collection consists of 4 documents, in each document there is a field "policyList" which is an array of objects. In first document policyList contains 3 objects, in second document only two and so on. So I have to filter documents in this collection in such way: 1) I need to keep in the "policyList" array only those objects that match to such condition: one of the fields are in a certain time interval, which means that must be a match in at least one of the fields(first field is "receivedDate" - which is located in the array at the first level of nesting - "policyList" or second field "policyStatusDate" - which is located in the array at the third level of nesting - "policiesArray", and if there is a match in one of abovementioned fields we return from the "policyList" full object, that means we cannot throw away from "policiesArray" any object). One match is enough, for example if I want to see documents from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022 I expect to see in the first document in the "policyList" array only first and third object, because first object matches by "policyStatusDate" - 20/02/2022 (match in one of the object in "policiesArray" is enough) and third object matches by "receivedDate" - 23/02/2022) and second object in first document I don't expect to see because both dates in this document are not in the period from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022; 2) if there are no any matches among objects in "policyList", that means "policyList" must be empty after filtering, and in such case we don't need to return this document. For example if I request for a documents from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022 I'm not expecting to see second document, because no "policyStatusDate" and no "receivedDate" are in requested time interval.

My aggregation request:

```
db.getCollection("offers2").aggregate([
{
  $project: {
  "agentId": "$agentId",
  "agentName": "$agentName",
  "policyList": {
      $filter: {
         input: "$policyList",
         as: "item",
         cond: {
         "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
            }, 
            {
               $and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
            }
         ]
         }
      }
  }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
  "agentId": "$agentId",
  "agentName": "$agentName",
  "policyList": "$policyList",
  "numPoliciesPerDate": {
    $cond: {  
      if: {$isArray: "$policyList"}, then: {$size: "$policyList"}, else: "0"
     }
    }
  }
  },
  {
  $match: {
    "numPoliciesPerDate": {$gte: 1}
     }
  }
])
```

After running this query I expect to receive first document with first object and third object in "policyList" array, but I received only third object (there is matching by "receivedDate" in this object ). Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "agentName" : "Yardi Gaondi", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "numPoliciesPerDate" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

...
So it seems that condition

```
 $and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
```

doesn't work correct. I think it's because it may be impossible to use dot notation when we work with nested arrays. So maybe somebody could help me to fix this aggregation query so that the requirements I described at the beginning will be fullfiled and in our case first object from "policyList" in first document will also be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  { "$set": {
      "policyList": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$policyList",
          "as": "policy",
          "cond": {
            "$or": [
              { "$and": [
                  { "$gte": [ "$$policy.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                  { "$lte": [ "$$policy.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
                ]
              },
              { "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$$policy.policyStatusDetail",
                  "initialValue": false,
                  "in": {
                    "$or": [
                      "$$value",
                      { "$reduce": {
                          "input": "$$this.policiesArray",
                          "initialValue": false,
                          "in": {
                            "$or": [
                              "$$value",
                              { "$and": [
                                  { "$gte": [ "$$this.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                                  { "$lte": [ "$$this.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
                              ]
                            }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$policyList" }, 0 ] } } }
)
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NX-nQpgCxNb)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this one will do the trick, just replace the dates with the correct format of your timezone:

```json
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$policyList"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "policyList.receivedDate": {
            $gte: ISODate("2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2022-03-01T03:00:00.000Z")
          }
        },
        {
          "policyList.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate": {
            $gte: ISODate("2022-02-01T03:00:00.000Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2022-03-01T03:00:00.000Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      agentId: {
        $first: "$agentId"
      },
      agentname: {
        $first: "$agentName"
      },
      policyList: {
        $push: {
          receivedDate: "$policyList.receivedDate",
          policyStatusDetail: "$policyList.policyStatusDetail"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "agentId": "$agentId",
      "agentName": "$agentName",
      "policyList": "$policyList",
      "numPoliciesPerDate": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isArray: "$policyList"
          },
          then: {
            $size: "$policyList"
          },
          else: "0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "numPoliciesPerDate": {
        $gte: 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, it's interesting decision. I see now that "policyStatusDetail" and "policiesArray" after running this query changed their type, now they are objects. One problem is that we lost one of the object in the "policiesArray". For example in first object of first document we had two objects in "policiesArray", First object matches to condition and second doesn't match, but according to requirements we cannot throw away the second object, we need to return "policiesArray" with both objects. I would be very grateful if somebody could help me to build a query without changing a way to store data

Comment: could we talk about this query in private conversation, what do you think about it?

Comment: @yakob yes we can talk about it to help you come up with the query.

Comment: Cool. @WiseCode I'm free for a next 6 hours. In what time and in which way I can connect you?