# How to access documents in nested arrays at the first and third level at the same time mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would be very grateful for any help.

```
  { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
        "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
        "agentName" : "Yard Gaondos", 
        "policyList" : [
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-16")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d86"), 
        "agentId" : NumberInt(2), 
        "agentName" : "Michelle Hazandi", 
        "policyList" : [
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-10"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-04-09")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-03-10"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-09")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("626da96932cb6043086eae42"), 
        "agentId" : NumberInt(3), 
        "agentName" : "Barbie", 
        "policyList" : [
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-04-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-05-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-05-16")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-03-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("626da96932cb6043086eae43"), 
        "agentId" : NumberInt(4), 
        "agentName" : "Mzandi", 
        "policyList" : [
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-05-10"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-09")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-01-10"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-02-09")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
        "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
        "agentName" : "Yardosh Gaondore", 
        "policyList" : [
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2014-03-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2012-02-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2012-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2013-03-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(3), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2014-01-16")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "receivedDate" : ISODate("2012-02-23"), 
                "policyStatusDetail" : [
                    {
                        "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                        "policiesArray" : [
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2014-01-20")
                            }, 
                            {
                                "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2013-01-19")
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

So collection consists of 5 documents, in each document there is a field "policyList" which is an array of objects. In the first document policyList contains 3 objects, in the second document only two and so on. So I have to filter documents in this collection in such way: 1) I need to keep in the "policyList" array only those objects that match to such condition: one of the fields are in a certain time interval, which means that must be a match in at least one of the fields(first field is "receivedDate" - which is located in the array at the first level of nesting - "policyList" or second field "policyStatusDate" - which is located in the array at the third level of nesting - "policiesArray", and if there is a match in one of abovementioned fields we return from the "policyList" full object, that means we cannot throw away from "policiesArray" any object). One match is enough, for example if I want to see documents from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022 I expect to see in the first document in the "policyList" array only first and third object, because first object matches by "policyStatusDate" - 20/02/2022 (match in one of the object in "policiesArray" is enough) and third object matches by "receivedDate" - 23/02/2022) and second object in first document I don't expect to see because both dates in this document are not in the period from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022; 2) if there are no any matches among objects in "policyList", that means "policyList" must be empty after filtering, and in such case we don't need to return this document. For example if I request for a documents from 01/02/2022 to 01/03/2022 I'm not expecting to see second document, because no "policyStatusDate" and no "receivedDate" are in requested time interval.

My aggregation request:

```
db.getCollection("offers2").aggregate([
{
  $project: {
  "agentId": "$agentId",
  "agentName": "$agentName",
  "policyList": {
      $filter: {
         input: "$policyList",
         as: "item",
         cond: {
         "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.receivedDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
            }, 
            {
               $and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
            }
         ]
         }
      }
  }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
  "agentId": "$agentId",
  "agentName": "$agentName",
  "policyList": "$policyList",
  "numPoliciesPerDate": {
    $cond: {  
      if: {$isArray: "$policyList"}, then: {$size: "$policyList"}, else: "0"
     }
    }
  }
  },
  {
  $match: {
    "numPoliciesPerDate": {$gte: 1}
     }
  }
])
```

After running this query I expect to receive first document with first object and third object in "policyList" array, but I received only third object (there is matching by "receivedDate" in this object ). Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62684847e9594c65cbaa5d85"), 
    "agentId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "agentName" : "Yardi Gaondi", 
    "policyList" : [
        {
            "receivedDate" : ISODate("2022-02-23T04:46:15.000+0000"), 
            "policyStatusDetail" : [
                {
                    "policyStsCode" : NumberInt(7), 
                    "policiesArray" : [
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-20T04:46:15.000+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "policyDetailedCode" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "policyStatusDate" : ISODate("2022-01-19T05:46:15.000+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "numPoliciesPerDate" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

... So it seems that condition

```
$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-02-01") ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$item.policyStatusDetail.policiesArray.policyStatusDate", ISODate("2022-03-01") ] }
              ]
```

doesn't work correctly right now. i will be grateful for your help to finish this query.

Comment: Please search for similar/identical questions before posting new questions.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72022363/1409374.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filtering documents containing three level nested arrays depending on the values in the most nested and least nested array mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020852/filtering-documents-containing-three-level-nested-arrays-depending-on-the-values)

Comment: when I tried to reproduce your issue, I get two items back from the aggregation ("Yard Gaondos" and "Barbie")

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).