# Mongodb $ operator for nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions

there is a wfs collection as follows:

```
{
_id:'1',
transitions:
  [
    {
     _id:'11',
     checkLists:
       [
        {
         _id:'111',
         name:'One',
        },
        {
         _id:'112',
         name:'Two',
        }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the sub sub document of _id:'111'
I have tried the following code but not working as expected, it returns all of 2nd level nested documents not the proper object

```
db.wfs.findOne(
    { 'transitions.checkLists._id':  ObjectId('111') },
    { 'transitions.checkLists._id': 1 },
  );
```

result:

```
{
transitions: [
  {
    "checkLists": [
      {
        "name": "One",
        "_id": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "Two",
        "_id": "112"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "checkLists": [
      {
        "name": "One",
        "_id": "111"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

appreciated any hint or solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {"transitions.checkLists._id": "111"}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      transitions: {
        $reduce: {
          "input": "$transitions",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.checkLists" ]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      checkLists: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$transitions",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item._id",  "111" ]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BctQdIJX-cS).

The `$reduce` is used to "flatten" your list, and the `$filter` is used to keep only the part you want.

This is based on [this solution by @rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020852/filtering-documents-containing-three-level-nested-arrays-depending-on-the-values) to a basically similar, but little more complex, problem. The solution here is just a simple version of it.